# Get relative from absolute url

Tags: javascript

I am new to this, so sorry if the question is stupid or easy.
I have a string variable that holds an absolute url. I want the relative url extracted from it.
Example: http://something.com/fizz/buzz => /fizz/buzz

Is there a library that I need to use, or should I write my own string manipulation function? If the later, should I go for regexp?

EDIT: is there a best practice for this? or do I need to write my own hack?

Comment: Check out this Gist https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561

Comment: You could remove everything before the third forward slash, if you are certain that the URL will always be in the format "http://example.com/"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for `http://something.com/fizz/buzz` and also for `something.com/fizz/buzz`

```
function getRelativeURL(the_url)
{
    // remove the :// and split the string by '/'
    var the_arr = the_url.replace('://','').split('/');

    // remove the first element (the domain part)
    the_arr.shift();

    // join again the splitted parts and return them with a '/' preceding
    return( '/'+the_arr.join('/') );
}
```

See it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3s15sbun/

Comment: is there a best practice for this in js? I come from a world where you need to use a library function to solve this kind of stuff.

Comment: @naic This is a good solution; for something as small as this, it would be overkill to include a library.

Comment: @naic i usually argue with people which say that is good for new programmers to use frameworks and libraries. They say that you can build faster and safer. I say that libraries and frameworks should only be used by people who can build them from scratch and understand them 100%. **Only** for **these** experienced people, libraries frameworks are a time-saver. For new programmers, it's a disaster. In your situation, you grew up on a library-dependent environment and without them you feel completely unprotected! I advice you to depend less in libraries and frameworks. Start writing code yourself

Comment: @naic and yes using this function is good practice, you can use it without feeling guilty. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname) on a link:

> The `HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils.pathname` property is a [USVString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USVString)
>   containing an initial '/' followed by the path of the URL.

```
function getUrlPath(url) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  return a.pathname;
}
getUrlPath("http://something.com/fizz/buzz"); // "/fizz/buzz"
```